# При запуске программы меняется язык ввода

Tags: delphi

При запуске программы из IDE Delphi меняется язык ввода. В моей программе все данные на русском, а Delphi меняет на английский...

Как этого избежать?

Comment: ???

Это проблема?

Comment: Проблема. В моей программе все данные на русском, а делфи меняет на английский...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно где-нибудь в обработчике `OnCreate()` или `OnShow()` главной формы устанавливать язык приложения (в плане раскладки клавиатуры, если вы об этом):

```
ActivateKeyboardLayout(LoadKeyboardLayout(PChar(IntToStr($409)), 0), KLF_ACTIVATE);
```

А вообще все это логично. Ведь когда система создает новое окно, то ему (окну) присваиваются "дефолтные качества" типичной сборки Windows, например, русскоязычной.

Comment: У меня-то меняется с русского на английский!)) Спасибо за ответ! Но теперь язык всегда меняется на русский, а хорошо бы сделать так, чтобы он менялся только, если делфи поменяла с русского на английский. Другими словами, как поймать тот момент, когда делфи меняет язык? Кто-нибудь подскажет, как это сделать?

Comment: Сам момент смены поймать нельзя, а вот проверять какой язык сейчас вполне возможно. и тогда по условию или менять раскладку или нет.

Comment: Собственно, язык-то меняет не делфи, а сама программа.